# Correct application of Miller theorem on a feedback two-stage transistor amplifier

Tags: amplifier, feedback, frequency-response

I'm trying to estimate the lower cut-off frequency of this two-stage amplifier with feedback, assuming a dominant pole exists at low frequency.

[image: CE+CS amplifier with RC feedback]

To do that, I want to apply the Miller theorem on the feedback impedance \$Z_F := R_F + \frac{1}{sC_F}\$, and then apply the SCTC (short-circuit time constant method) on the three resulting capacitances (\$C_S\$ and the two from Miller's theorem).

[image: Small signal model and Miller theorem]

To apply the Miller theorem, I need to know the gain of \$v_o\$ over \$v_e\$, i.e. \$K := \frac{v_o}{v_e}\$, and then I can split \$Z_F\$ into

$$Z_1 = \frac{Z_F}{1-K} =: R_1+\frac{1}{sC_1},\qquad Z_2 = \frac{Z_F}{1-\frac{1}{K}} =: R_2+\frac{1}{sC_2}.$$

Finally with the SCTC method I estimate the lower cut-off frequency \$f_L = \frac{1}{2\pi}\omega_L\$:

$$\omega_L \approx \frac{1}{R_S^{SC}C_S} + \frac{1}{R_1^{SC}C_1} + \frac{1}{R_2^{SC}C_2}.$$

**How do I properly calculate the gain \$K\$?**
Do I need to consider \$C_F\$ (and \$C_S\$) short circuits, thus calculating \$\frac{v_o}{v_e}\$ «at mid-band» and then assume that, at the cut-off frequency \$f_L\$, \$K\$ will be \$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\$ this value due to the dominant pole assumption? Or is this incorrect?

Comment: The pole's can be easily found \$ \frac{1}{\omega (R_S + R_P||R_{in})C_s} \$ and \$\frac{1}{\omega R_F C_F}\$ and the mid frequency gain will be around \$K \approx \frac{R_F}{R_E} + 1\$

Comment: Are you sure that you can use the Miller theorem in this example?

Comment: @G36 Provided that I have a method to find the mid frequency gain \$K\$, my question is if I can use it directly with the Miller theorem (if possible to use it at all). I'm not sure if I can use it when studying the frequency response (since it is not a "constant" gain as required by the theorem).

Comment: For me, you cannot use the Miller theorem in this case.  There is no Millers' effect here because VE voltage will have the same phase (polarity) as a Vout voltage.

Comment: As far as I understand, the Miller theorem works no matter the phase of the gain (provided we know this gain); while Miller's effect occurs only in specific cases.

Comment: Unless errors, simulated gain for K = vo/ve = 3.326. Global gain = vo/vs = 2.857.